# Date selection within group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have  table which have two dates column and compare dates in the below fashion such that date1 should be less than date2 but date1 should be the latest date within it's group.

[image]

I am able to get the results as I wanted but the problem is that it might not be the best way as in my original table I have millions of records and around 30-40 columns

so while writing the select , I will be taking the max(col1), max(col2),...max(col40) which would be very tedious and not the right approach, I would like to know if there is any better way to get the desired ouput.

code to replicate

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy_tab (
    empid int,
    date1_start date,
    date2_start date,
    name_emp varchar(255)
);
 

INSERT INTO Dummy_tab VALUES
  (1, '2018-02-27','2018-02-28', 'Eric'),
  (1, '2016-02-28','2018-02-28', 'Eric'),
  (1, '2018-01-28','2018-02-28', 'Eric'),
  (2, '2018-10-28','2018-12-28', 'Jack'),
  (2, '2018-02-28','2018-12-28', 'Jack'),
  (2, '2018-11-28','2018-12-28', 'Jack'),
  (2, '2018-12-20','2018-12-28', 'Jack'),
  (2, '2018-12-28','2018-12-28', 'Jack'),
  (3, '2018-12-28','2018-12-31', 'Jane'),
  (3, '2018-12-28','2018-12-31', 'Jane');

  select empid,
         max(date1_start),
         max(date2_start),
         max(name_emp)
  from Dummy_tab
  where date2_start > date1_start
  group by empid
```

Comment: Just to check - the additional 30-40 columns - are they the same across all rows for a given employee, or are they different? Similarly, for a given employee (say, Eric), are values for the other 30-40 columns taken all from one row, or can they be taken from different rows (e.g., are you just interested in the *last* row, or calculations based on all rows for that person)?

Comment: @DaleK the columns are all same for all employees, yes value for eric and others are taken from one row but date 2 should be greater and date 1 should be the latest date among all the entry of eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns the expected output

```
with rn_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by empid order by date1_start desc) rn
    from Dummy_tab
    where date2_start > date1_start)
select * 
from rn_cte rc
where rn=1;
```

Output

```
empid   date1_start date2_start name_emp    rn
1       2018-02-27  2018-02-28  Eric        1
2       2018-12-20  2018-12-28  Jack        1
3       2018-12-28  2018-12-31  Jane        1
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit after clarification that all data is in one row - just want to find the latest row per person.*

In terms of getting the correct result (e.g., finding the 'latest row' for each person but with date1 earlier than date2) then use/start with @SteveC's answer. It gives you what you want, and while it does a full index scan it will generally have good performance (and I've upvoted it as such). If you only ever want to run this infrequently, or you're happy to wait for however long it takes (e.g., 10s), then that's your answer and you don't need to do any more.

However, if it takes too long, you may want to consider further notes here about optimising how data is read from the table. These may speed up processing especially if you have lots of rows for each person. If, on the other hand, you only have a few rows per employee, these may make little difference.

(Note I've also cleaned up some of the stuff not relevant, based on OP's answers to comments).

---

Given that you need date1_start to be less than date2_start, you will always need to do a full table or index scan: It won't be able to seek to a specific point in the index because it needs to calculate the difference for every line.

You then burn CPU doing sorts/group-bys. Sorting (and group-by, which requires a sort) tend to be the things that take the most CPU time in most queries.

You could try

- modifying the group-by to group by more fields rather than using MAX
- using CTEs and/or windowing functions

However you'll still have the same problems: it still needs to do the full index scan plus sorts.

If the query isn't going fast enough, one of the problems may relate to the amount of data being read. If you can reduce that, it may go faster.

Firstly, if you have many rows per employee (and your table has a primary key and isn't a heap), you could do a process to first identify the PKs for the relevant rows, then join that to the original table to get all the values for that row. In this case you can do a MAX(date1_start) rather than a ROW_NUMBER(), so you don't need to do a full sort. However, it then needs to do lookups to the clustered index again. This could be sped up with indexes (e.g., an index on emp_id, date1 and date2) reducing reads.

If you can change the table - and have a great need for this to run frequently - you could add a [persisted computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) (e.g., CASE WHEN date2_start > date1_start THEN DATEDIFF(day, date2_start, date1_start) ELSE NULL END) and then put an index on it and empid, meaning you could do calculations with those (e.g., finding the maximum date difference by employee).

However, it may decide to do a clustered index scan anyway if you have to do too many index seeks/key lookups (It depends how many rows each individual has - if each person has a lot, this could really help. If each individual only has a few rows, it may not).